# How to unset updatedAt on nodeJs mysql sequalize?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

help me how to unset updatedAt when update data in mysql sequalize? i want to update status data without update timestamp on updatedAt.

help me to solve this problem. thanks

Here my controller

```
const updateData = async (req, res) => {

    let id = req.params.id
    const data = await dbModel.update(req.body, { where: { id: id }})
    res.status(200).send(data)

}
```

thanks for all response my question.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to indicate `silent: true` as an option:

```js
 const data = await dbModel.update(req.body, { where: { id: id }, silent: true })
```

See [static `update`](https://sequelize.org/v5/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#static-method-update)

Comment: so many thanks for your answer and solve my problem.

Comment: const data = await dbModel.update(req.body, { where: { id: id } }, silent: true) this work for me